# Is TensorFlow Lite useful when it comes to ML model processing numerical data?

Tags: java, python, spring, tensorflow

I'm working on a smart mobile thermostat optimizing and saving energy in Android and Spring. An ML model should be applied to Spring Boot app which is to be a server with which Android app is going to communicate.

To create an ML model I need to provide data set which will include historical average outside temperatures, current outside temperature and room temperature which should be updated regularly, heat transfer coefficient of the building, room area and cubature and average energy(heat) use in heating season concerning average room size.

Therefore, I'd like to find out if this tool (TensorFlow Lite) could be useful and particularly what AI methods and algortithms would fit best to this application to process numerical data and create model which would control stove when to switch on and off according to user's preferences (exact temperature,time of obtaining the desired result, saving energy). If need be, I'd be grateful if you could give me some other recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

[TensorFlow Lite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite) is particularly the best way to run ML models ( with limited supported operations ) on Android. I have personally used in image classification [here](http://https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.health.inceptionapps.skinly).

> TensorFlow Lite is the successor of TensorFlow Mobile which is currently deprecated but is still used.

In your problem, you have some features and the label is binary ( 0 for OFF and 1 for ON ).
You can gather some data and train a Keras model on it.

> Keras is an open source neural-network library which is also build on TensorFlow and is available in `tf.keras` module.

You can find the tutorials on their website. After saving the model to a .`h5` file you need to convert it to a .`tflite` file which is our TensorFlow Lite model. See this [file](https://web.archive.org/web/20190507132939/https://github.com/shubham0204/Melanoma_Classification_with_TF/blob/master/TFLiteBufferConverter.py).

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file( keras_model_path )
tflite_buffer = converter.convert()
open( tflite_file_path , 'wb' ).write( tflite_buffer )
```

You can keep this model in your app's assets folder and load it in Android using `Interpreter` class. You can see this [file](https://github.com/shubham0204/Skinly_for_Melanoma/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/health/inceptionapps/skinly/TFRecognizerClasses/SkinDiseaseRecognizer.java).

You can see the app "Skinly". It uses TensorFlow Lite. Python project is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20200919111110/https://github.com/shubham0204/Melanoma_Classification_with_TF) and Android project is [here](https://github.com/shubham0204/Skinly_for_Melanoma).

**Tip:**

As you used the word *server*, there is [TensorFlow.js](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/) available which makes ML models in JavaScript.
You can load Python models in it too.

Also, you have host your model on [Firebase ML Kit](https://firebase.google.com/products/ml).

Hope that helps.